# How to check if a specific file exists in a shared folder using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to check the existence of file which is present on shared location using powershell command.

I am using below query,which is giving wrong result for shared folder.

Test-Path " \computer\Software\aaa.txt"

Please help me to sort out the issue..

Comment: This sort of question probably fits better at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Try `Test-Path "\\computer\Software\aaa.txt"`, if that doesn't work you have something else that's wrong.

Comment: A single slash at the beginning indicates the root of the current working drive. So, for example, if your current directory is **C:\Users\user3215521**, it will look for **aaa.txt** in **C:\computer\software**. Since that directory doesn't exist, the result will always be false, which is what I assume you're getting. The path with the double backslash in @Tanner's comment looks for the file in a share called **software** on a computer called **computer**, which is presumably what you want.